# Unit Testing a method with a large string

Tags: c#, string, unit-testing

I'm currently using C#, but I believe the question applies to more languages.

I have a method, which takes a string value, and throws an exception, if it's too big. I want to unit test it that the exception is correct.

```
int vlen = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(value);
if (vlen < 0 || 0x0FFFFFFF < vlen)
   throw new ArgumentException("Valid UTF8 encodded value length is up to 256MB!", "value");
```

What is the best way to generate such a string? Should I just have a file of that size? Should I create such a file every time running unit tests?

Comment: You can generate a string using a loop, stringbuilder, or array.

Comment: Consider using a stream and a stream reader, instead of having the whole string in memory.

Comment: do you need to test for `< 0`?

Comment: @RufusL I am not sure, it isn't my code originally. I don't see how it could return a negative value here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string` has a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor) that lest you specify a length and a characer to repeat:

```
string longString = new string('a',0x0FFFFFFF + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append('a', 0x10000000);
string s = builder.ToString();

//Console.WriteLine(s.Length);

YourMethodToTest(s);
```

This takes no measurable time at my machine and I'm sure there won't be a serious performance issue on your machine either.

Answer (score 0):

What I would usually use in Unit Tests is a package called [`AutoFixture`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture).

With that you can do the following to generate a large string:

```
string.Join(string.Empty, Fixture.CreateMany<char>(length))
```